# Method object is not subscriptable in Neural Networks Code

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, neural-network

I have started to learn ML and Neural networks for some college project while learning I have encountered a problem in the code which I am not able to fix.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow import keras 

data = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist

(train_images,train_labels),(test_images,test_labels) = data.load_data()

class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat', 'sandal', 'Shirt', 'sneaker', 
'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

train_images = train_images/255.0
test_images = test_images/255.0

model = keras.Sequential([
keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28,28)),
keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
 ])

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

prediction = model.predict

print(class_names[np.argmax(prediction[4])])
```

The error I am getting is:

> **TypeError: 'method' object is not subscriptable.**

Answer (score 1):

`model.predict` is a method of the `model`-class, so you must call it like a function. See TF documentation here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#predict

So in your case you must provide the data the model should generate predictions on, e.g. `model.predict(test_images)`.

With `model.predict` you are just referencing the method of the class, into which you try to index with `[4]`, hence the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call the predict method on something: like model.predict(x) where x is some input you want to predict on. For example calling predictions = model.predict(test_images) should work. Then you can select a prediction like np.argmax(predictions[4])

Comment: Thank you so much made a simple mistake which i couldn't see